# Extra amount credited to my foreign currency account and mistakenly I spend it. What should I do?

Tags: india, banking, foreign-exchange, law

I deposited some thai baht into my foreign currency account in india which amounts to Rs.250000 but in my account the same amount was credited three times and from different person. My initial deposit was not credited at all. Without knowing this I used 2.5 Lakh assuming its the amount I deopsited

Comment: `same amount was credited three times and from different person` Why didn't you contact your bank ?  `My initial deposit was not credited at all.`  Why didn't you contact your bank, again ?

Comment: I am not India, my family took the amount using cheque(they were told to withdraw 2.5 Lakh Rs that i deopsited from my account) and i dont get bank notification in my mobile phone. I just checked my account as routine check and after seeing balance I further checked the balance statement and found    wrong deposit.

Comment: Read what happened to Susan Madakor under similar circumstances http://www.nytimes.com/2000/01/05/nyregion/for-lottery-winner-who-wasn-t-bank-account-remains-frozen.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact the bank, ask them why your Rs 250,000 didn't get credited to your account. Also highlight the erroneous credits.

Comment: Yes it is less than a month since I deposited, I will do that. Just out of curiosity, what if I never saw the account and mistake it for currency difference, spend rest of the money and close the account. Having given clean chit to my account during account closing they cannot hold the bank error against me. Right?

Comment: In the UK, taking the money with no intent of paying it back is theft, and people have gone to jail for it. I have no idea what Indian laws say about this, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: @trojans As part of account opening terms and conditions you would have signed a statement that you would bring to notice any descripences to banks notice. You would still be liable to pay back. Depending on the amount and effort bank may or may not pursue the case.